# how to add custom property in model MVC 4 for my query linq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Sorry for my bad english, but i have problem in my project

shop_list table relationship with shop_item table via PK key of shop_list table and listID field in shop_item table. shop_item table relationship with favorite(id,userid,shop_item_id) table via PK key

How i can get favorite for each shop_item with user loging??

i can't put 1 property for count it?. How to solution ?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEgtL.jpg

My database. i use linq query :

```
var q = (from ulist in db.shop_list
                             where ulist.shop_user.username.Equals(username)
                             select new 
                             { 
                                shoplist = ulist,
                                listitem = ulist.shop_item.ToList(),
                             });
```

How in each shop_item i select, i can check favorite for user like

```
favorite = exitem.shop_favorite.Where(o=> o.userid == userid ).Count()
```

Comment: It is not clear what is shop_list, shop_user etc. if you give more detail on the attribute and relationship that will help us to understand the problem.

Comment: You have users and shops. Each user can have multiple shops as favorites. Shop_Favorite table has both userid and itemid. Now, you want to have list of users with fav list of shops. Am I correct?

Comment: i want check item i get by list is favorite with user login y/n?. I    have problem with ajax,

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is define a class FavoriteList

```
public class FavoriteList
{
   public List<shop_list> {get;set;}
   public List<shop_item> {get;set;}
   public int favCount {get;set;}
}
```

Modify your code

```
select new FavoriteList
        { 
        shoplist = ulist,
        listitem = ulist.shop_item.ToList(),
        favCount =exitem.shop_favorite.Where(o=> o.userid == userid ).Count()
});
```